# ANDROID: Is it possible to run a specific function every 10 seconds while the application is running?

Tags: android

I have three activities
1 is the main activity
2 is some other activity that does something
and 3 is some other activity that does some storage management with sqlite

in this 3 activity I have a function that updates some data on the database's table

I want every 10 seconds to call a function in order to update this table

ScheduledExecutorService can do what I want. However I'm not 100% sure. If I'm on the 1 activity will it be able to call the function from the 3 activity even though I'm on the 1?

I also found alarmmanager but I don't want the update of information to be happening even when I close my application, I want it to happen only when I have the application open!

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TimerTask` or `Handler`. Here is a tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html